# How to pass variables that are arguments in user defined functions to subfunctions in r

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, paste, cat

I have a general problem in understanding how to create a user defined function that can accept variables as arguments that can be manipulated inside the defined function. I want to create a function in which I can pass variables as arguments to internal functions for manipulation. It appears that many of the functions I want to use require the `c()` operator which requires quotes around the arguments.

So my function has to be able to pass the name of a variable from a dataframe into the quotes for `c()` and other functions requiring quote strings.  I read through many post on `paste0`, `paste` and `cat(x)`, but I cannot figure out how to solve my problem completely.

Here is a simple dataset and shortened code to help structure the problem. Here I just want to be able to provide a dataframe, and three variables. The function should provide the mean of the variable in the y position for each combo of the `x` and `z` variable. The resultant aggregate table should have the names of the variables provided as arguments to XTABAR as column headers.

```
n=50
DataTest = data.frame(  xcol=sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), ycol = rnorm(n, 5, 2), Catg=letters[1:5])

XTABAR<- function(DS,xcat,yvar,group){ 
  library(plyr)
  #library(ggplot2)
  #library(dplyr)
  #library(scales)
  localenv<-environment()
  gg<-data.frame(DS,x=DS[,xcat],y=DS[,yvar],z=DS[,group] )
  cnames<-colnames(gg)
  ag.gg<-aggregate(gg$y, by=list(gg$x,gg$z),FUN=mean)

  colnames(ag.gg)<-c(cat('"',cnames[1],'"'),cat('"',cnames[2],'"'),cat('"',cnames[3],'"'))
  return(ag.gg)
}

XTABAR(DataTest,"xcol","ycol","Catg")
```

This code is as close as I can get to solving the simple problem. I don't know how to remove the quotes from the column names nor how to get rid of the NA's.

Thank you for any help on the logic and or code.

Comment: Without looking further into what this function does - what about `colnames(ag.gg)<-c(xcat, yvar, group)`?

Comment: lukeA, you solved my temporary problem thank you. I am new to stackoverflow. How do I give you credit?

Comment: Then welcome to SO. :) There's a check mark next to the votes counter. If you find a solution that you like, you can accept that as an answer by clicking on the check mark. PS: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to provide good examples and get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. I was not too clear about the desire to quote the names but we put stars around them in the code below.  If that is not needed then remove the `setNames` statement.

```
XTABAR <- function(DS, xcat, yvar, group) {
    ag <- aggregate(DS[yvar], DS[c(xcat, group)], mean)
    setNames(ag, paste0("*", names(ag), "*"))
}
```

Test it:

```
XTABAR(DataTest, "xcol", "ycol", "Catg")
```

giving:

```
   *xcol* *Catg*   *ycol*
1       1      a 5.700938
2       2      a 5.292628
3       3      a 5.204395
4       1      b 4.054289
5       2      b 5.119659
6       3      b 4.050799
7       1      c 2.937309
8       2      c 5.696256
9       3      c 6.773029
10      1      d 5.323572
11      2      d 3.430644
12      3      d 4.892041
13      1      e 4.024070
14      3      e 5.038122
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't have enough rep points to vote up but this works.

Answer (score 0):

I make heavy use of `eval(parse(text=))` for this purpose. It evaluates a character string as though it is a command. For example:

```
> x <- "5 + 5"
> eval(parse(text=x))
[1] 10
```

Using your example, this should work if you input your parameters as character strings:

```
XTABAR<- function(DS,xcat,yvar,group){ 
  library(plyr)
  #library(ggplot2)
  #library(dplyr)
  #library(scales)

  var1 <- eval(parse(text=paste(DS, "$", xcat, sep="")))
  var2 <- eval(parse(text=paste(DS, "$", yvar, sep="")))
  var3 <- eval(parse(text=paste(DS, "$", group, sep="")))

  localenv<-environment()
  gg<-data.frame(x=var1, y=var2, z=var3)
  cnames<-colnames(gg)
  ag.gg<-aggregate(gg$y, by=list(gg$x,gg$z),FUN=mean)

  colnames(ag.gg)<-c(cat('"',cnames[1],'"'),cat('"',cnames[2],'"'),cat('"',cnames[3],'"'))
  return(ag.gg)

}
```

I'm going to go ahead and anticipate a criticism of my answer.

```
> require(fortunes)
Loading required package: fortunes
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink
the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

Mr. Lumley is probably correct in this case. There are probably simpler solutions, but this should at least get you going.

Comment: Unfortunately the parse solution did not work. Thanks though. I downloaded the pdf from the fortunes package. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

To set the column names, use `colnames(ag.gg) <- c(xcat, yvar, group)`.